# Multiple popup modal boxes

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created a page with a div that when clicked produced a popup modal popup box as per this how to - http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp

The code I have so far is:

JS -

```
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');


// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("drawer1");


// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

CSS -

```
/* The Modal (background) */

.modal {
  display: none;
  /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1;
  /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px;
  /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
  height: 100%;
  /* Full height */
  overflow: auto;
  /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  /* Black w/ opacity */
}
/* Modal Content */

.modal-content {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
  animation-name: animatetop;
  animation-duration: 0.4s
}
/* Add Animation */

@-webkit-keyframes animatetop {
  from {
    top: -300px;
    opacity: 0
  }
  to {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 1
  }
}
@keyframes animatetop {
  from {
    top: -300px;
    opacity: 0
  }
  to {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 1
  }
}
/* The Close Button */

.close {
  color: white;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.modal-header {
  padding: 2px 16px;
  background-color: #5cb85c;
  color: white;
}
.modal-body {
  padding: 2px 16px;
}
.modal-footer {
  padding: 2px 16px;
  background-color: #5cb85c;
  color: white;
}
#drawer1 {
  position: absolute;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: red;
  width: 22.5%;
  height: 9.5%;
  top: 5%;
  left: 2%;
}
#drawer2 {
  position: absolute;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: red;
  width: 22.5%;
  height: 9.5%;
  top: 5%;
  left: 26.5%;
}
```

HTML -

```
<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<div id="drawer1"></div>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">×</span>
      <h2>Modal Header</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Some text in the Modal Body</p>
      <p>Some other text...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <h3>Modal Footer</h3>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>


<div id="drawer2"></div>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">×</span>
      <h2>Modal Header</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Sodjshdjhfjhsdfjhsdjhfjdy</p>
      <p>kjbhdfkjbfkjdnbskjfnbdskjbf</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <h3>Modal Footer</h3>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

This works fine for one div but what i really want is to have multiple divs on the page that will each open their own modal box.

Is there a way to do this using this code or am I going to have to look at a different approach?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have multiple modals then you should create a class the wraps the functionally. In each class you have a reference to the dom element that is displayed and methods to remove and add it from the page.

ie

```
function modal(title, description, ) {
  this.element = //create element
}
modal.prototype = {

destroy and add methods
}
```